# js callee.caller as object instead of function

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an OOP project in JS and I want to find the owner object of a the caller.callee

Example:
myObj.someFunc is called by yourObj.someFunc
I want to get a reference to yourObj from within myObj.someFunc and I need to do this without passing a reference to yourObj as a parameter.

Something like callee.caller.object would be nice, but of course, doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `this` binding of the calling function -- unfortunately, the ECMAScript standard provides no way to obtain this.

Further, `arguments.callee.caller` has also been removed in ECMAScript 5, so you should no longer rely on using it.

Comment: Let's say I do myObj.someFunc(yourObj.someFunc) - Can I get the 'this' binding from the param coming into myObj.someFunc or would I have to do something like myObj.someFunc(yourObj, 'someFunc') (not preferred)?

Comment: @Jackson: When you do `yourObj.someFunc`, the expression is already evaluated and all you have left is a reference to the function -- there's no way to get back `yourObj` from that. So yes, you would have to pass `yourObj` separately.

Comment: As much as I hate to accept "this isn't possible yet" as the answer, it's the answer as far as I can tell. Thanks for your help.